# Setar atributos em um único bloco JS

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso? Eu to repetindo muito código com o `setAttribute` em um único elemento, então estou pesquisando se existe alguma forma de fazer isso de um jeito mais organizado e otimizado, mas não achei ainda.

Abaixo vai um EXEMPLO do que to fazendo e um EXEMPLO do que queria fazer se possível:

**Link qualquer que irei utilizar no exemplo:**

```
<a class="teste"></a>
```

**Código JS que estou fazendo pra setar os atributos:**

```
document.querySelector('.teste').setAttribute('href', 'https://www.teste.com')
document.querySelector('.teste').setAttribute('title', 'Site de Teste')
document.querySelector('.teste').setAttribute('id', 'idteste')
```

**Como eu queria se possível ou algo similar:**

```
document.querySelector('.teste').setAttribute(['href', 'title', 'id'], ['https://www.teste.com', 'Site de Teste', 'idteste'])
```

Teria algo similar a isso ja nativo do JavaScript?

Comment: Nativamente não tem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poderia fazer usando uma função, passando como parâmetros o elemento, e os atributos e os valores como arrays, e fazer um `for` em qualquer uma das arrays setando os atributos:

```js
function setAttr(el, atts, vals){
   for(var x=0; x<atts.length; x++){
      el.setAttribute(atts[x], vals[x]);
   }
   
   console.log(el);
}
setAttr(document.querySelector('.teste'), ['href', 'title', 'id'], ['https://www.teste.com', 'Site de Teste', 'idteste']);
```

```html
<a class="teste">link</a>
```

---

Outra forma (ainda melhor) é passando dois parâmetros: o elemento e um objeto com pares *atributo:valor* para a função e fazer um `for...in`:

```js
function setAttr(el, atts){
   for(var x in atts){
      el.setAttribute(x, atts[x]);
   }
   console.log(el);
}
setAttr(document.querySelector('.teste'), {'href': 'https://www.teste.com', 'title': 'Site de Teste', 'id': 'idteste'});
```

```html
<a class="teste">link</a>
```

> Pra ser bastante sincero, eu preferiria repetir mesmo como você está
>   fazendo. Usar uma função para aplicar atributos, na minha opinião, é
>   trocar 6 por meia-dúzia. Não vejo muita vantagem e acho que fica até pior de ler.

Neste caso, eu apenas atribuiria o elemento a uma variável para não repeti-lo várias vezes:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.teste')
el.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.teste.com')
el.setAttribute('title', 'Site de Teste')
el.setAttribute('id', 'idteste')
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes simplificar atributos desta maneira:

```
document.getElementById("test").href = "http://www.cnn.com/";
document.getElementById("test").id= "novoID";
document.getElementById("test").required = false;
document.getElementById("test").disbled= false;
```

Em vez de procurarespor ID podes usar `getElementByClass` para procurares por class.

Mas penso que não podes mudar mais que um atributo de uma só vez usando arrays, corrijam se tiver errado.

Comment: Este código vai buscar o elemento `test` ao DOM `4` vezes, que é precisamente o que o autor está a tentar evitar.